# I am new to python and do not know much about coding but wanna learn more on how to create working codes

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program where the program takes a list and reverses its elements if the elements are divisible by 2 but not by 3.
I will give you an example of what I want so that you can guide me on how to meet that. Let us say that I have (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) as my input I want the output which is divisible by 2 but not by 3. The normal answer for this would be 2 and 4 as 6 can be divided by 3. But I want that answer to be in reverse order i.e. 4 and 2.
I am able to make it up to the point where I can make it divisible by 2 but can't go further than that.
Here are the codes that I am able to go up to.

Python program to print all the numbers 
divisible by 2 and not by 3 for a given number

Result function with N:

```
def result(N): 

    # iterate from 0 to N 
    for num in range(N): 

            # Short-circuit operator is used  
            if num % 2 == 0: 
                print(str(num) + " ", end = "") 

            else: 
                pass
```

Driver code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 

    # input goes here 
    N = 6

    # Calling function 
    result(N)
```

Comment: You are not checking if the number is divisible by 3, and you are doing nothing to reverse the input or output.

Comment: Since you want in reverse order you can use the loop: `for num in range(N, 0, -1)`, which for N = 6, would be 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.  To test if divisible by 2 but not 3 use: `if num % 2 == 0 and num % 3 != 0:`

Comment: @DarrylG thank you for your help finally my code is working.

Answer (score 0):

We'll iterate backwards over the range and check each number:

```
N = 6
for i range(N, -1, -1):  # Step backwards in the range [N,-1)
    if i % 2 == 0 and not i % 3 == 0:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Python program to print all the numbers 
# divisible by 2 and not by 3 for a given number 

# Result function with N 
def result(N): 

    # iterate from 0 to N 
    for num in range(N, 0, -1): 

            # Short-circuit operator is used  
            if num % 2 ==0  and num % 3 != 0: 
                print(str(num) + " ", end = "") 

            else: 
                pass

# Driver code 
if __name__ == "__main__": 

    # input goes here 
    N = 6
    # Calling function
    result(N)
```